# Optimizing shifts in Knuth long division algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, knuth

I'm trying to roll out my own Bignum library. Class Bignum stores values in `std::vector<uint32_t> v;` encoding full little-endian (words/elements of v little-endian, most significant word in v[0]; for example value of 0x1100000003 would be stored as {0x11, 0x3} in `v`).

Profiling shows two most time-consuming operations for `%=` operator in my usage, `-=` and `>>=`. I can't do much about the first, it's about as optimally written as possible in given scenario, but I should definitely be able to optimize the right-shift in the modulo.

In particular, if I'm using this for RSA, with the classic public exponent of 0x10001 (binary: 10000000000000001) after first subtraction the number (*this) drops by about 15 bits of magnitude, and next bunch of comparisons `if ( *this >= r )` return false, the `r >>= 1` doing its laps uselessly.

I'd much rather use something similar to `int n = SignificantBits() - rhs.SignificantBits();` I use to guesstimate the initial left shift of rhs, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to calculate the value.

In short, if I replace `--n;` `r >>= 1;` with `n -= x;` `r >>= x` how would I go about calculating the `x` ?

```
uint32_t Bignum::SignificantBits() const
{
    return (v.size() == 0)?0:(32*v.size() - __builtin_clz(v[0]));
}

Bignum& Bignum::operator%=(const Bignum &rhs)
{
// irrelevant edge/degenerate case mitigation code stripped, assume *this > rhs

    int n = SignificantBits() - rhs.SignificantBits();
    Bignum r(rhs);
    r <<= n;

    while( n >= 0)
    {
        if ( *this >= r)
        {
            *this -= r;
        }
        --n;
        r >>= 1;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: BTW for RSA (and similar usage), you can use Montgomery modular multiplication to avoid most expensive modulo operations.

Comment: Couldn't you implement shifting in O(1) by using views rather than actually shifting?

Comment: @Luatic Dunno, I could certainly shift by multiples of 32 bits by just pointing at a different word, maybe even by 8 with some #pragma pack magic. I don't think I can shift by an arbitrary number of bits like that, and if I can, I don't know how.

Comment: Also note that algorithm would be insecure in any case due to input-dependent execution times; i.e., a [side-channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) vulnerability.

Comment: @BrettHale Kinda doubt it, runtimes differed by good half a second run to run, with exactly the same inputs, the allocator randomizing the times quite thoroughly. But sure long enough input can DoS this.

Comment: @SF. Brett's concern isn't about DoS (denial of service), it's about leaking confidential information. I would not rely on the allocator "randomizing" the times; this does in no way meet the bar for cryptographical random (in fact the allocator is probably pretty deterministic, so a sophisticated attacker might use that knowledge; and even then, there's still statistics - over many runs, we can expect the allocator impact to "average out"). A *single bit* of information extracted, if this can be repeated often enough, suffices to leak the entire secret.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error more than logical thinking I came up with:

```
    x = r.SignificantBits() - SignificantBits();
    if(x < 1) x = 1;
    n -= x;
    r >>= x;
```

It produces correct results and offers about 20% performance gain in my tests. Times in seconds:

```
                          operator%= : 13.3654134396 //new %=
                     PowMod_improved : 14.0268638200
                          operator^= : 15.1284481500 //old %=
                        PowMod_worse : 17.0191601600
```